# Single Channel Mosaicked Image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb

I'm trying to convert a 3-channel rgb raw image to a one channel image in Matlab (or any other conversion software for that matter). I've tried concatenating but that was still unsuccessful. Any other suggestions? 
The raw image I found online and I personally don't care which format it's in (whether NEX/ARW/etc). Just need to get it to one channel.

Thanks

Comment: Converting a 3 channel RGB image to a one band grayscale image is trivial in matlab, just use [`rgb2gray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2gray.html)

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to demosaick a three band image but first want to convert it to one band. When I make it grayscale, run my algorithm, and finally display it at the end it's still grayscale. When I convert it back to RGB, it doesn't show any of the artifacts that I know exist when demosaicking.

Comment: In the past, I received an image where it tried to mirror what one would get directly off the CCD (one channel, but couldn't 'view' it as if you did it was all black)- basically an intensity file.

Comment: Are you sure you mean demosaicing? Try reading about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demosaicing). Demosaicing starts with a single channel image which represents the sensor output and is then converted into a 3-band RGB image. There are lots of methods for demosaicing and it is dependant on the sensor. Some of the more common ones are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_filter_array)

Comment: Exacltly. I'm trying to use an image I've taken on my camera and every time I try to open it in matlab, it's already 3-band. I don't know how to take the raw image from my camera and keep it in the single channel. I've tried DNG converter, and other image converters but they all convert my raw image to 3-bands.

Comment: You need to export the raw format image. This is a setting on your camera and has nothing to do with matlab or programming. It is also highly dependant on which camera you are using.

Comment: I have a raw image from my camera (specifically the ARW file from a sony camera, but i've downloaded raw images from Nikon/Canon cameras as well). I also have demosaicking algorithms. I am just stuck as to how to get the raw image into matlab as one band to simulate the single channel image that represents the sensor output. You're suggesting that it's a camera setting?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ARW in particular. Have you looked at the file in something like a text editor? I would guess you have to read it with file I/O level tools.